# How to control invocation spike in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dropbox

I have an AWS lambda function that uploads a file to the dropbox using its api.
It works well in normal but when there are hundreds~thousands of requests in a short amount of time (within a few min, for example), dropbox file upload requests are throttled and get penalty to retry in 30/60/300 seconds. This obviously causes time-out in lambda functions (which is not efficient in pricing term as well).

Can someone help me how to control such a spike in lambda invocation? I tried to set the reserved concurrency for that function but it doesn't seem so reliable because lambda invocations are throttled and retries randomly.

Or is it something that I need to resolve with dropbox side? So that they do not put limit to their api calls?

Comment: Well, what is your goal, which part do you want to throttle? Currently dropbox throttles you, you can circumvent that by throttling lambda. But if you actually want max throughput you need to talk to dropbox, upgrade your plan or whatever.

Comment: @luk2302 Does plan upgrade resolve the api rate limit issue?

Comment: I have no idea, I do not know any dropbox apis. That comment is a general note.

Comment: Once Lambda is running, you want it to go super-fast. So anykind of waiting is not a good idea. A queue would be the logical answer to your problem. SQS can use delivery delay (max 15min) to hide the incoming messages from Lambda. The control logic of this queue should be implemented depending on your needs.

Comment: @ClémentDuveau what if 100 messages are pushed to the queue at the same time, will they be released all at once after the delivery delay lapses?

Comment: Yes. Delivery delay allows you to wait before releasing the new messages. Your lambda could set it and re-publish the message to the queue for example.